# Sql Server Computed Column Specification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column `USER_ID` which I set as a "Computed Column Specification" with a formula of `(newid())`. But accidentally, I did not select the "Is Persisted" option.

Meanwhile, I have inserted some of the records in the same table. Now I want to change it to being "Is Persisted".

But while changing process, I get an error

> Computed column 'USER_ID' in table 'Tmp_USER_PROFILE' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Please suggest how I can change it from "Is Persisted=No" to "Is Persisted=Yes".

Comment: You can't, because `NEWID()` is nondeterministic, and nondeterministic computed columns can't be persisted. You probably intended to give the column a *default* value of `NEWID()`, rather than have the value change on every row retrieval. Recreate the column as `USER_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID()`. Note that your current rows already don't have stable IDs, so you're not losing any information by dropping the column.

Comment: you can not use newid() as calculated columns however you can use trigger for workaround. please see following code --->>   go 
create table Table1 (ID int,Column2 uniqueidentifier  ) 
 go 
create trigger t1
on Table1 after insert as
begin
 update t1
 set t1.Column2 = NEWID()
 from Table1 t1 join inserted t2
 on t1.id = t2.id
end 
 go 
insert into Table1(ID)
select 1
 go